# Material design animation when selecting ImageCell in ListView

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, material-design

I'm new to mobile dev and Xamarin in particular so forgive me if this is somewhat basic but I've been Googling my brains out and can't find a good answer to this one ...

I have a MasterDetail page set up with the primary navigation scheme of my app as the master and the detail page loading via reflection on a TargetType property of the object bound to my ListView in the Master. Basically straight from the Xamarin sample for MasterDetail page like so:

```
    public class MasterPageItem
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string IconSource { get; set; }
        public Type TargetType { get; set; }
    }

    public MainMenu ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        var masterPageItems = new List<MasterPageItem>();
        masterPageItems.Add(new MasterPageItem
        {
            Title = "Events",
            IconSource = "Icon.png",
            TargetType = typeof(MainPage)
        });
        masterPageItems.Add(new MasterPageItem
        {
            Title = "Categories",
            IconSource = "Icon.png",
            TargetType = typeof(Categories)
        });
        masterPageItems.Add(new MasterPageItem
        {
            Title = "Tags",
            IconSource = "Icon.png",
            TargetType = typeof(Tags)
        });

        listView.ItemsSource = masterPageItems;
    }

    void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var item = e.SelectedItem as MasterPageItem;
            if (item != null)
            {
                listView.SelectedItem = null;

                var mdPage = this.Parent as MasterDetail;
                mdPage.IsPresented = false;

                mdPage.Detail = new NavigationPage((ContentPage)Activator.CreateInstance(item.TargetType))
                {
                    BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("1976D2")
                };
            }
        }
```

Xaml Page:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
      <ListView x:Name="listView" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" SeparatorVisibility="None" ItemSelected="OnItemSelected">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <ImageCell ImageSource="{Binding IconSource}" Text="{Binding Title}" TextColor="White" Tapped="OnCellTapped" />
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
  </ContentPage.Content>
```

My goal is to try to add a simple material design-type background color animation on the press of the ListView item (like this example: http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/ripple-click-effect-google-material-design).

It looks like the ImageCell class doesn't implement IAnimatable so binding to the Tapped event on that element won't help, and the ListView class itself doesn't seem to implement any sort of an Item or Row element that is itself animatable. The only option I see is to animate the entire ListView, which I'm actually able to do but it's obviously not what I'm trying to achieve.

There also doesn't seem to be a SelectedItemBackgroundColor property or the equivalent on the ListView itself? I feel like I'm missing something major, like the fact that this can't be done cross-platform and has to be platform specific but that seems like a major oversight in Xamarin.Forms, no?

I have a few other ListViews where I'd like to utilize a similar UX so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this and it looks like the ripple effect is provided by default when using AppCompat. The MasterDetailPage sample hasn't been updated for this which is probably why it's not working there. To add AppCompat and Material design to your Forms Android project, check out this [guide](https://blog.xamarin.com/material-design-for-your-xamarin-forms-android-apps/).